# How to change the parameter name using resources in Phoenix framework Router

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Is there an option to make this ->

```
resources "users", MyApp.UserController
```

generate paths with parameter name other than `:id` ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the `param` parameter in the [resources/4 macro](http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Router.html#resources/4):

```
resources "users", MyApp.UserController, param: "name"
```

This will generate the following routes:

- GET /users => :index
- GET /users/new => :new
- POST /users => :create
- GET /users/:name => :show
- GET /users/:name/edit => :edit
- PATCH /users/:name => :update
- PUT /users/:name => :update
- DELETE /users/:name => :delete

Following are the additional options for resources:

> This macro accepts a set of options:
>
> :only - a list of actions to generate routes for, for example: [:show, :edit]
>
> :except - a list of actions to exclude generated routes from, for example: [:delete]
>
> :param - the name of the paramter for this resource, defaults to "id"
>
> :name - the prefix for this resource. This is used for the named helper and as the prefix for the parameter in nested resources. The default value is automatically derived from the controller name, i.e. UserController will have name "user"
>
> :as - configures the named helper exclusively
>
> :singleton - defines routes for a singleton resource that is looked up by the client without referencing an ID. Read below for more information

Comment: Thank you. It turned out to be rather a foolish question ... I don't know how I missed it in the docs.

Comment: Yes of course, I wanted to do that when you had justanswered but it told me to wait and I forgot, thanks for reminding

Comment: Cheers for linking to `resources/4` - I was using Phoenix's "routing" guide and it made no mention of options like `:name`